How to prevent styles from outer container to spill over into content of CKEditor5?
I'm embedding CKEditor inside a CMS's "Admin" application to edit the content of a website's page.
Goal:Since CKEditor is a WYSIWYG editor, I would like the content of CKEditor to mimic the style  the website.
Problem:Styles used by Admin spill over into CKEditor. How can this be prevented/remedied?
I can:

Load my own script/stylesheet into Admin.
Load the styles of the website into Admin "as is", or wrap/nest the themes' styles in my own selectors before loading.

Limitations:

I have no control over the styles loaded by Admin.
I have no control over the theme/styles used by the website itself.

I've tried:

Permutations of all: inherit|initial|revert|unset.
Improving the specificity of the theme's css by wrapping/nesting it inside more specific selectors.

